# syntax error, I don't see one :S

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

Apparently i'm getting a syntax error, but I don't see any issues with my code!

```
if rs.EOF then
    'User doesn't exist, create the record
    query = currentDate&",'"
    query = query + password & "','"
    query = query + "user', '"
    query = query + email & "', '"
    query = query + fname & "', '"
    query = query + sname & "'"

    handle = add_to_database("users","jdate,password,perms,email,fname,sname",query)
    response.write handle
else
    response.write "Error: User already exists, please use a different email address"
end if
```

Here is the add_to_database function

```
function add_to_database(where,column,values)       
    'Create query
    sql = "INSERT INTO " & where & " (" & column & ") VALUES (" & values & ")"
    on error resume next
    'Add images to database
    conn.Execute sql,recaffected

    if err<>0 then
        add_to_database = err.description &":"&sql&"<br />"
    end if

    'Destroy connection
    sql = ""
end function
```

This is the error that is written to the page

```
Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.:INSERT INTO users (jdate,password,perms,email,fname,sname) VALUES (#2013/8/2#,'af453d19feb2520c8c0d30fb39ebd211','user', 'martynleeba@gmail.com', 'Martyn', 'Ball')
```

Comment: That's the first time I've seen the hash character used as a delimiter of a date value. I'm curious. What does that mean? Which database engine supports it?

Comment: @Zec: It's MS Access syntax for dates.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What database engine are you using? The syntax you're using for `jdate` (`#2013/08/2#`) is most likely not accepted by ADO or OLEDB. You should stick to standard `YYYY-MM-DD` format in SQL.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that. The date format is usually fine, works for all of my other scripts when adding to database. Using MS Access Database

Comment: Please don't put information that's important to your question in the comments; it's very difficult to find in the clutter, and when it's extremely relevant you need to make sure people see it so you can get help. You can always [edit] your own question to add details (including tags you forgot) or clarify things. :-) As I said, you should use the standard ANSI format for dates; the # formats work directly in Access, but may not through other data access layers like ADO or OLEDB. It would probably help for troubleshooting if you did proper error handling instead of `on error resume next'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `users` table includes a field named `password`.  But `password` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#P), so can confuse the db engine when it finds it in a query.  Rename that field if possible.  If you must keep the name as is, enclosed it in square brackets to signal the db engine it is an object name.

```
handle = add_to_database("users","jdate,[password],perms,email,fname,sname",query)
```

Comment: I think (could be mistaken) Access uses backticks for reserved words

Comment: Either backticks or square brackets will work.  I use brackets as a matter of habit.